# class myString new programmer

Tags: c++, constructor

```
class mystring
{

public:

    mystring(const char x[])
        : capacity(1024)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i)
        {
            if (x[i] == '\0') break;
            s[i] = x[i];
            length++;
        }
    }
    mystring()
        : capacity(1024), s('\0'), length(0)
    {}
//etc...

private:

    const int capacity;
    char s[1024];
    int length;
};
```

I'm getting this error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:19:0:
mystring.h: In constructor ‘mystring::mystring()’:
mystring.h:21:44: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char’ to ‘char [1024]’
         : capacity(1024), s('\0'), length(0)
```

I don't under stand what's going on. I'm a bit new to constructors. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't really matter that the error is inside a constructor. It clearly says that you can not assign `char` to `char[1024]`.

Comment: In the first constructor you're treating `s` as an array, `s[i]`. In the second constructor you're treating `s` as a `char` variable, `s('\0')`. It can't be both.

Comment: Yeah i'm a total newb. Thanks a lot fellas. I was just overlooking the obvious.

Comment: Note too that the first constructor doesn't initialise `length` before it increments it... that's undefined behaviour and could manifest in many ways, easily including a garbage value for `length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `s('\0')` to `s("\0")`

WHEN you use single quotes, it's a single character. You must use double quotes to test it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting right now is because that you are trying to put `char` into `char[]`.

`char[]` is an array of char and char itself is just a char;
regularly, `char[]` is defined as `char str[] = "Test";`

Think about that and try to fix your code!
Hope this helps